# How to return the first day of next six months in Apex

Tags: apex

I need to return a list of the first day of the next six months in Apex, I've tried this but it seems that need some changes.

```
public class firstDayOfNextSixMonths {
    public List<Date> getFirstDaysOfSixMonths(){ 
    List<Date> dates = new List<Date>();
    date myDate;
    date nextMonth;
    date firstDayNextMonth;
       for(Integer i = 1; i <= 6 ; i++){
        nextMonth = myDate.addMonths(i);
        firstDayNextMonth = nextMonth.toStartOfMonth();
        dates.add(firstDayNextMonth);
     }
    return dates;
  }
}
```

I'll really apreciate your colaboration.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SFSE. Please take a [tour] and read [ask]. That's great that you have shared with us what have you tried so far but it would be even greater if you could edit your question and tell us what's the result you receive, comparing to what should be received.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

Change this `date myDate;` line to `Date myDate = Date.today();`
As you did not instantiate the date, it will throw null pointer exception.

Comment: Thank you so much.